# How to call jquery that is stored in external javascript file from html file

Tags: html

//employeeForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Employee Information</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="EmployeeFormStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="EmployeeModuleBase.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body class="body">
    <h3 class="header">Employee Information</h3>
    <form class="form" method="post" id="employeeInfoForm" name="employeeInfo" action="ProcessEmployeeInfo.php">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fname">First Name:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_1"><input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_1" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="surname">Surname:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_2"><input id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_2" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="gender">Gender:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_3">
                        <select name="Gender" id="Gender">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_3" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Title">Title:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_4">
                        <select name="Title" id="Title">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                            <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_4" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="ID No">ID No.:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_5"><input id="IDNo" name="IDNo" type="text" maxlength="13"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_5" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_6"><input id="MobileNumber" name="MobileNumber" type="text" maxlength="12"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_6" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="email">Email Address:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_7"><input id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_7" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for= "address">Address:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_8"><input id="AddressLine1" name="AddressLine1" type="text"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_8" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="eftd_9"><input id="AddressLine2" name="AddressLine2" type="text" size=30/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_9" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="eftd_10"><input id="AddressLine3" name="AddressLine3" type="text" size=30/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_10" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="location">Location:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_11">
                        <select name="Location" id="Location">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="Sebokeng">Sebokeng</option>
                            <option value="Sharpville">Sharpville</option>
                            <option value="Evaton">Evaton</option>
                            <option value="Boipatong">Boipatong</option>
                            <option value="Bophelong">Bophelong</option>
                            <option value="Vanderbijlpark">Vanderbijlpark</option>
                            <option value="Vereeneging">Vereeneging</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_11" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for= "postalcode">Postal Code:</label></td>
                    <td id="eftd_12"><input id="PostalCode" name="PostalCode" type="text" maxlength="5"/></td>
                    <td id="validatortxt_12" class="red-text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="btnSubmit" class="butt" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" type="submit"/>
                        <input id="btnClear" class="butt" name="btnClear" value="Clear" type="submit"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>   
</body>
</html>


EmployeeModuleBase.js
jQuery().ready(function ()
 {
    $('#employeeInfoForm').submit(function()
      {
        var postForm = true;
        $(':input').each(function(index)
         {
             if ( $(this).val() == "" )
             {
               if ($(this).attr("id")!="EmailAddress")
                {
                 $('#validatortxt_' + (index + 1).toString()).text(" *");
                }

                postForm = false;
              }
              else
              {
                $('#validatortxt_' + (index + 1).toString()).text("");
                postForm = true;
              }
        });

        return postForm;
      });
 };
```

basically what m trying to achieve is to validate the form using jquery code in external js file.but how does the form calls the jquery code in js external file...?

Answer (score 0):

you append the ready method to the loading of jQuery

```
jQuery().ready(function ()
```

you should append the event to the document and not just to the jQuery itself. then it should load up when the document is ready to go and the DOM is there for the handler to append to.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your external file, just have a plain 'old fashion' function.  Then you can call it as needed (the function can use jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(DocReady);

function DocReady()
{       
    AssignClickToToggleButtons();
    ColorCodeTextBoxes();
    DoValidation();
}
```